# matlab - How to get int64 from a Java method returning a long?

Tags: java, matlab, type-conversion

According to [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-data-returned-from-a-java-method.html), when a Java method returns a `long`, it is converted to a `double` before being assigned in Matlab.

Precision has been lost. I am interested in the lower digits of the `long` returned by the Java method. A `double` cannot represent them, but Matlab's `int64` can. (This is clear by considering that both types have 64 bits, and a `double` uses some of them to represent the exponent.)

If I had control of the Java code, I could return an array with one element, containing the `long` — in this case Matlab keeps them as `int64`s, but in my case I'm calling a library function.

Currently, the best way I can see is writing a wrapper in Java that will call the method and return the answer in an array. But there are portability issues with this approach. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yikes, good info.  I have a project where I'm passing around int64s back and forth, I'll need to back and check this!

Comment: One thought -- if you return a java.lang.Long rather than long, you could (in matlab) do .toString() and bring the result in as a string, and convert back in matlab.

Comment: i.e. Matlab could then get an int64 by using sscanf(char(wrapperFun().toString),'%ld').

Comment: In Matlab `java.lang.Long(java.lang.Long('123456789123456789').longValue())` gives `123456789123456784`, so it converts it to double before sending it to the `Long` constructor. So the method you suggest requires compiling Java code, in which case you might as well return an array, it's probably faster than parsing strings.

Comment: I think your suggestion is the only way - except you can probably return a java.lang.Long rather than long[] if you prefer. Even trying to use java reflection doesn't stop MATLAB from converting the long to double.

Comment: This is tough. I think you're stuck writing a Java wrapper layer like you say. But what portability issues do you see with that? Deploying a JAR with Matlab code is usually easy and should be portable. That's one of the selling points of Java.

Comment: @AndrewJanke I suppose it should be fine if I compile it with the target being the earliest possible version of Java. Java is always backwards-compatible, right?

Comment: That should work fine. Yes, new versions of Java will run code compiled against older versions (and in many cases vice versa) and their back-compatibility track record is quite good. Easy approach: build it with the version of Java that's shipped with the earliest version of Matlab that your code will be running on. Totally normal and supported for Matlab development. And because your wrapper layer will be thin (not using advanced Java standard library features) your code will probably be compatible in both directions and you won't need to worry about the JDK version anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been essentially answered in the comments, but just for completeness, the best way to receive a Java `long` into Matlab as `int64` unharmed does seem to be writing a small Java wrapper which calls whatever method you have and returns the response in a `long[]`.

(If the code is to be distributed, consider compiling that Java class with a target JVM version that is somewhat earlier than the latest — otherwise some users will be forced to upgrade their JVM to run your software, and some of those won't have admin rights to do that.)

Answer (score 4):

If the `long` results that your Java method returns are in the range [-9,007,199,254,740,992 to 9,007,199,254,740,992], then you don't need to do anything at all in your code.  You can convert the result back to Matlab's `int64`, without any loss of precision.  All integers in that range can be represented as `double` numbers without a loss in precision, because the value can be stored in the 53-bit significant binary digits offered by the 64-bit representation of `double` values.

You can find more details in Chapter 8 (Floating-Point Arithmetic) of my book [Code Quality: The Open Source Perspective](http://www.spinellis.gr/codequality) or any other textbook covering floating point arithmetic.

The following program demonstrates the accuracy of the `double` representation for the 100 million integers at the end of the exactly representable range.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    volatile long long n1, n2;
    volatile long long p1, p2;
    volatile double d;

    /* Include one number outside the range, to show that the test works. */
    n1 = -9007199254740993ll;
    p1 =  9007199254740993ll;
    for (i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        d = p1;
        p2 = d;
        if (p1 != p2)
            printf("%lld != %lld\n", p1, p2);

        d = n1;
        n2 = d;
        if (n1 != n2)
            printf("%lld != %lld\n", n1, n2);
        p1--;
        n1++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's good to know. It's not a set-and-forget solution, because, for example, the number of nanoseconds since epoch (1970) is greater than that number (this is what led to posting the question in fact), and in general, you could pack pixels into longs, or pack some other data into them — not an everyday situation, but could happen from time to time.

Comment: Also, I thought that `volatile`s only help with multi-threaded code?

Comment: `volatile` instructs the compiler to avoid optimizing code related to that variable. Without it a clever optimizing compiler could optimize away parts of my code, because they don't do anything useful.

Comment: The traditional Unix representation of time has two fields: one for seconds from epoch, and one for microseconds.  Each one of these can be comfortably represented in 53 bits.

Comment: I was storing time as returned by `java.lang.System.nanoTime()`. This is just to illustrate that you may think "oh, I'll never need to deal with such large numbers", but then many days later you run into unexpected behaviour and it takes some unnecessarily wasted time tracking it down to mixed up, due to truncated digits, timestamps messing up things somewhere causally downstream. For example.